# Keyboard navigation not working for datepicker only in mozilla firefox

Tags: datepicker, mozilla, keyboard-navigation

I am using kendo datepicker

If user selects date and then on date input field user move cursor using left-right keyboard arrow then cursor is not moving.

Left-right keyboard navigations are working for Chrome and IE but not working for mozilla firefox.

Comment: do you use kendo in combination with  other libs ? what version of kendo d oyou use?

Comment: I am using kendo with angularjs. below code: <input onkeyup="formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy');" id="start" class="searchdatepicker"
                                           ng-model="fromEncounterDateFilter" ng-change="startChange(); setCustomDate('startChange')" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" maxlength="10"/>

Comment: please update your question with code snippets as in that article
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ . So it would be easier to help you